# Descartes’ innate idea of extension

Tags: reference-request, descartes

Can you give the most clear and self-contained quote out of Descartes’ works where he states that *extension* is an innate idea?

I’ve read the third meditation again, but I didn’t anything easily quotable there. It’s only derivable from the general argument that he considers extension an innate idea, if I understood him correctly.

Comment: The wax argument perhaps:"Let us attentively consider this, and, abstracting from all that does not belong to the wax, let us see what remains. Certainly nothing remains excepting a certain extended thing which is flexible and movable...  We must then grant that I could not even understand through the imagination what this piece of wax is, and that it is my mind alone which perceives it."

Comment: See *Principia*, I art.8 and II art.1.

Comment: See also *Med*, III : Among my ideas, in addition to the one that displays me to myself (about which there can be no difficulty at this point), are others that represent God, corporeal and inanimate things, angels, animals, and finally other men like myself. [...] As to the ideas of corporeal things, [...] I notice that there are only a very few things in them that I perceive clearly and distinctly: namely,
size, or extension in length, breadth, and depth; shape, [...] and motion, or alteration in position.

Comment: See also *Med*, Reply to First Objections (Caterus) : "I have a complete understanding of what a body is when I think that it is merely something having extension, shape and motion, and I deny that it has anything which belongs to the nature of a mind. Conversely, I understand the mind to be a complete thing, which doubts, understands, wills, and so on, even though I deny that it has any of the attributes which are contained in the idea of a body. This would be quite impossible if there were not a real distinction between the mind and the body."